# HIdden expression has invalid input string

Tags: reporting-services

Have an error: THe hidden expression for tablix Group23 contains an error, input string not in correct format

I did not creaet this and am new to the location and having to fix all.
here is the hidden expression

```
="Your screening results..." +VBCRLF+VBCRLF+"•  Your Body Weight was :" & (Fields!weight_loss.Value) & "lbs" 
+ VBCRLF+ "•  Your Body Mass Index (BMI) , which is based on your height and weight, was:" & (Fields!bmi.Value)& " " & "[Healthy Range: 18.5-24.9]"
+VBCRLF+ "•  Your waist circumference was:" & (Fields!waist.Value) & "inches." & "[Healthy Range:]" &IIF(Fields!gender.Value="M",35,40)
+ VBCRLF+ "•  To be in the healthy BMI range , your recommended weightshould be between " & (Fields!goal_wt_low.Value) & "and" &(Fields!goal_wt_high.Value) & "lbs." & "You told us that.." +VBCRLF+VBCRLF+
"• With regard to weight loss," & IIF(Fields!weight_loss.Value=1,"you are satisfied with the way you are now and have no desire to change.", IIF(Fields!weight_loss.Value=2,"•  you have considered making healthier choices."
, IIF(Fields!weight_loss.Value=3,"you have seriously considered making healthier choices and are ready to make a change.",IIF(Fields!weight_loss.Value=4,"you have started making healthier choices."
,IIF(fields!weight_loss.Value=5,"you have already made changes for a healthier lifestyle and are trying to maintain them.",IIF(Fields!weight_loss.Value=99,"you are not sure how satisfied you are with your current body weight.",nothing))))))
```

Comment: You haven't provided too much: Has this always returned an error? If not, what changed? When does this return an error? What parts, in particular, do you need help with?

Comment: i just started on friday here, so I do not know if always thrown error or not. I am not sure what else to supply, i supply the parameter then preview the report and it errors .  The parameter is from a dataset that is created from a query of the database.

Comment: What version of SSRS? If a recent version, then start breaking this apart into multiple placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

While that is a lot of data I think the problem is probably pretty simple.  I am betting one of those data types is not of a type of string, or varchar/nvarchar in the database.  It is basically stating: "I cannot add to a string with a number until you cast it."

I would guess you just need to add CSTR( ) around the Fields.(thing).Value expressions to cast them as strings.  If it is still bombing after this I would try a piece at a time and delete everything past the first expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a string value is not a boolean response that is needed for a Hidden expression. Hidden has 2 acceptable answers, True and False. A string expression would never evaluate to a boolean response.